# Saving columns from an SQL table into an array using Python

Tags: python, sqlite, chart.js

Im trying to pull data from my database and put it in a format where it could be displayed in chart.js. Im using python and my database is using sqlite3. Ive managed to pull the necessary values from the table and ive printed it in a table format to check, but Im not sure where to go from here.

```
from os import mkdir
import sqlite3

try:
    conn = sqlite3.connect('foldername/db.sqlite')
except sqlite3.OperationalError:
    mkdir('foldername')
finally:
    conn = sqlite3.connect('foldername/db.sqlite')

cursor = conn.cursor()

room_no = 1

cursor.execute(
    "SELECT room, strftime( '%H:00', date ) AS HOUR, SUM(count) AS DENSITY FROM crowd WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date) = strftime('%Y-%m-%d','now') AND room = ? group by HOUR order by HOUR asc",(room_no,))
for row in cursor:
    print('{0} : {1}, {2}'.format(row[0], row[1], row[2]))

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

To clarify, the output is currently being printed like this:

```
1 : 09:00, 3
1 : 10:00, 4
1 : 11:00, -2
1 : 12:00, 1
1 : 13:00, 1
1 : 14:00, 1
```

But I need to get the different columns into an array like this:

```
['09:00','10:00','11:00',...]
[3, 4, -2,...]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `zip(*...)` in python to [`transpose`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) your data.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT room, strftime( '%H:00', date ) AS HOUR, SUM(count) AS DENSITY FROM crowd WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date) = strftime('%Y-%m-%d','now') AND room = ? group by HOUR order by HOUR asc",(room_no,))
data = cursor.fetchall()
data = list(zip(*data))
```

`data[1]` will then be `['09:00','10:00','11:00',...]` (`(data[0])` being the room)

Comment: I replaced the print line with that and added print(data), but it ignored the first entry and printed it in a list like
[('1', '1', '1', '1', '1'), ('10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '15:00'), (-2, 1, 1, 1, 1)]. Is there a way to somehow split this array into three separate ones?

Comment: You should be replacing it *before* your loop and remove the loop entirely. You iterate over one entry in the cursor and then fetch all - meaning you missed the first entry.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up, youve helped a lot. Would like to add that it prints it as a tuple not a list but I at least know how to convert between the two.

Comment: @pynoob you can use `list(map(list, zip(*data)))` instead if you want them as lists